# VB.Net embedded font not working in windows XP

Tags: .net, vb.net, fonts, embedded-resource

I want a specific font to display on certain buttons in an application so have chosen to include it in the project as a resource.

I then .addMemoryFont to a new PrivateFontCollection by the way of the Marshal namespace and then set the font to my new font family.

This works on Windows Vista, Windows7 and Windows 8 (preview) but will not work on windows XP which my app has to support.

There is no error on XP .. the font just doesn't display.

I have also tried embedding the font as a file and loading it through a stream object  - Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resource)

This again works on everything but XP, any thoughts? Thanks

Here's the function that I load the resource with:
For this testing I have added AVP.TTF (widely available, non commercial) as a resource called AVP.

I use button.Font = LoadFontResource(9.75, FontStyle.Regular) in the client.

```
Public Function LoadFontResource(ByVal Size As Single, ByVal style As FontStyle) As Font
    _fontsResource = New PrivateFontCollection
    Dim fontMemPointer As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(My.Resources.AVP.Length)
    Marshal.Copy(My.Resources.AVP, 0, fontMemPointer, My.Resources.AVP.Length)
    _fontsResource.AddMemoryFont(fontMemPointer, My.Resources.AVP.Length)
    Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(fontMemPointer)
    Return New Font(_fontsResource.Families(0), Size, style)
End Function
```

Comment: Post code that reproduces the problem and a link to the trouble font.

Comment: Why do you need to support Windows XP.  In less then 17 months it won't even be supported by Microsoft.

Comment: @Ramhound, There are plenty of reasons to support XP.  It's not exactly a fringe need.

Comment: @Ramhound: OS support would have nothing to do with people buying my clients software.

Comment: Do not release the memory until you are sure that the font will no longer be used.

Comment: @Hans: the AddMemoryFont call appears to add a NEW font to the GDI+ Font Collection and no longer refers to the pointer so releasing the memory is correct.

Comment: That's an assumption, not backed-up by any documentation.  Version 1.10 of gdiplus.dll fixed a lot of quirks, XP has version 1.00

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a method to get Embedded Font Causes Protected Memory Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11173457/using-a-method-to-get-embedded-font-causes-protected-memory-error)

Comment: No, I said "appears" as in through testing it does. Leaving it in memory makes no difference to this in XP. Removing the pointer cause no exceptions also, since you asked for code I thought you may have tested that yourself. I had already read that solution before posting my question.

Answer (score 0):

Writing the embedded font to a temporary file and then using .AddFontFile leads to a more stable performance in XP. Thanks Hans for pointing me down the old GDI+ route.